# How to arrange all the words inside mustache braces with comma in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a html markup like this :

```
 <div>
   <p> My name is {{ name }} </p>
   <p>I learn {{ lang }} </p>
   <p>I am a {{ prof }} </p>
<div>
```

I want a javascript function that can identify all the words inside the mustache braces and arrange them with commas. I assume it will look something like this :

```
 arrange("div"); // name, lang, prof
 // Output should not be in array
// i.e. [ name, lang, prof ]
```

Output may be in string ! Can this be done without any external framework ?

Comment: Don't you have access to those variables where you render the template? You should be able to build your string there without having to get anything from the DOM.

Comment: I am new to javascript, please add an example

Comment: If the output is an array, just convert it to a string with `.join()`, like in `["name", "lang", "prof"].join(",")`, which would be `"name,lang,prof"`